# Create a Hash using JSON in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i need to make below hash data..please check it and help me out . i am new in rails so please help me

```
{tvs => [{name=>"faysal"
          videos = > [],
          seasons => [{name => "season1",
                       videos => [],
                       episodes => [{name => "episodename"
                                     videos =>[],{name=>"episodename2",videos =>[]}}]
                       }]
        }]
}
```

for it i have make method below

```
def all_shows_with_videos
   @arr = []
   @t = Tv.all
    @t.each do |v|
      if v.videos.present?
        @arr << v
      end
      v.seasons.each do |s|
        if s.videos.present?
          @arr << s
        end
       s.episodes.each do |e|
         if e.videos.present?
           @arr << e
         end
       end
     end
    end
    respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render :json => @arr }
    end 
  end
```

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: @SanderGarretsen my question is that i want to make such type hash using json. that i have mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

```
def all_shows_with_videos
   @arr = []
   Tv.all.each do |v|
     obj = {name: v.name} # or however you get name
     if v.videos.present?
       obj[:videos] = v.videos
     end
     obj[:seasons] = []
     v.seasons.each do |s|
       season = {name: s.name} # or however you get season name       
       if s.videos.present?
         season[:videos] = s.videos
       end
       season[:episodes] = []
       s.episodes.each do |e|
         if e.videos.present?
           season[:episodes] << e
         end
       end
       obj[:seasons] << season
     end
     @arr << obj
   end
   respond_to do |format|
     format.json {render :json => @arr }
   end
end
```

You could do this a lot nicer with more methods

```
def all_shows_with_videos
  arr = Tv.all.map do |tv|
    obj = tv.map_videos
    obj[:seasons] = tv.map_seasons
  end 
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render :json => arr }
  end
end
```

In `Tv` model

```
def map_videos
  {name: name, videos: videos || []}
end

def map_seasons
  seasons.map do |s|
    {name: s.name,
     videos: s.videos || [],
     episodes: s.episodes.map {|e| {name: e.name, videos: e.videos || []}} 
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: hi @Nermin , thanks for help. can you give me your skype id or any contact. i want to learn ruby on rails. can you teach me?? i am new in ROR

Comment: thanks @nermin its help me much. please give me your contact email address. my is faysalpk34@gmail.com, i am waiting for your kind response

Comment: Sorry find other sponsor.

Comment: listen. your first method is not give me complete requirement. please review it. i give you again my requirement.

Comment: actually videos associate with Tv, Seasons, Episodes also.mean TV have videos, Season have videos, Episodes have videos.now if Tv have videos, then tv name and video return else check in season, if season have videos then it return TV name and Season name or videos, else it go to episodes and check they have videos, if yes then return tv name , season name or episodes that have videos.

Comment: i think you get now it well

Answer (score 0):

```
def all_shows_with_videos
 @arr = []
 @t = Tv.all
  @t.each do |v|
   @arr << t.as_json(
     only: :name,
     include: {
       :videos,
       seasons: {
         only: :name,
         include: {
           :videos,
           episodes: { only: :name, include:{ :videos }}
          }
        }
      }
   )
  end
 respond_to do |format|
  format.json {render :json => @arr }
 end 
end
```

Comment: Read this Doc: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json

Comment: actually videos associate with Tv, Seasons, Episodes also.mean TV have videos, Season have videos, Episodes have videos.now if Tv have videos, then tv name and video return else check in season, if season have videos then it return TV name and Season name or videos, else it go to episodes and check they have videos, if yes then return tv name , season name or episodes that have videos.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo ,,,, finally i got my requirement

```
 def all_shows_with_videos
    @arr = []
    tvs = Tv.all
    tvs.each do |tv|
      tv_tmp = {:name => tv.name, :id => tv.id}
      tv_tmp[:videos] = tv.videos
      tv_tmp[:seasons] = []
      season_tmp = {}
      tv.seasons.each do |season|
        season_tmp = {:name => season.name, :id => season.id}
        season_tmp[:videos] = season.videos
        season_tmp[:episodes] = []
        season.episodes.each do |episode|
        season_tmp[:episodes] = {:name => episode.name, :id => episode.id} if episode.videos?
        end
        tv_tmp[:seasons].push(season_tmp) if !season_tmp[:videos].blank? or !season_tmp[:episodes].blank?
        end
      @arr.push(tv_tmp) if !tv_tmp[:videos].blank? or !tv_tmp[:seasons].blank?
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {render :json => @arr }
    end 
  end
```

its output below

```
[
    {
        "name": "Iron Man",
        "id": 95,
        "videos": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Trailer 1",
                "site": "Youtube.com",
                "link": "Google.com",
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": null,
                "videoable_id": 95,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-05-26T07:05:39+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            }
        ],
        "seasons": []
    },
    {
        "name": "How I Met Your Mother",
        "id": 100,
        "videos": [
            {
                "id": 13,
                "name": "Trailer 1",
                "site": null,
                "link": "google.com",
                "quality": "1020",
                "video_type": "Trailer",
                "videoable_id": 100,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-06-09T10:05:03+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            }
        ],
        "seasons": []
    },
    {
        "name": "my tv",
        "id": 124,
        "videos": [
            {
                "id": 59,
                "name": "Trailer 1",
                "site": null,
                "link": "google.com",
                "quality": "1020",
                "video_type": "Trailer",
                "videoable_id": 124,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-06-20T06:59:32+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            }
        ],
        "seasons": []
    },
    {
        "name": "Game of Thrones",
        "id": 151,
        "videos": [
            {
                "id": 129,
                "name": "",
                "site": null,
                "link": null,
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": "Season",
                "videoable_id": 151,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-09-02T11:13:40+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            },
            {
                "id": 130,
                "name": "",
                "site": null,
                "link": "",
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": null,
                "videoable_id": 151,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-09-02T11:13:40+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            },
            {
                "id": 131,
                "name": "",
                "site": null,
                "link": "",
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": null,
                "videoable_id": 151,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-09-02T11:13:40+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            }
        ],
        "seasons": []
    },
    {
        "name": "Under the Dome",
        "id": 160,
        "videos": [],
        "seasons": [
            {
                "name": "Season Specials",
                "id": 267,
                "videos": [],
                "episodes": {
                    "name": "Inside Chester's Mill",
                    "id": 1112
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Once Upon a Time",
        "id": 165,
        "videos": [
            {
                "id": 184,
                "name": "ggggggggg",
                "site": null,
                "link": "x268hqr",
                "quality": "320px",
                "video_type": "Clip",
                "videoable_id": 165,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-12-23T17:54:30+05:00",
                "video_source": "dailymotion",
                "video_source_cd": 2
            }
        ],
        "seasons": [
            {
                "name": "Season Specials",
                "id": 301,
                "videos": [],
                "episodes": {
                    "name": "Magic Is Coming",
                    "id": 1778
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Legends",
        "id": 169,
        "videos": [
            {
                "id": 106,
                "name": "Legends",
                "site": "YouTube",
                "link": "youtube.com/watch?v=12-nyZLqvxo",
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": "Trailer",
                "videoable_id": 169,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-08-15T10:46:07+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            },
            {
                "id": 108,
                "name": "trailer",
                "site": null,
                "link": "youtube.com/watch?v=12-nyZLqvxo",
                "quality": "1020",
                "video_type": "Trailer",
                "videoable_id": 169,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-08-29T17:24:01+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            },
            {
                "id": 109,
                "name": "episodes",
                "site": null,
                "link": null,
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": "Episode",
                "videoable_id": 169,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-08-29T18:55:28+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            },
            {
                "id": 110,
                "name": "episodes",
                "site": null,
                "link": null,
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": "Episode",
                "videoable_id": 169,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-08-29T18:56:50+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            },
            {
                "id": 111,
                "name": "episodes",
                "site": null,
                "link": null,
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": "Episode",
                "videoable_id": 169,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-08-29T18:57:22+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            },
            {
                "id": 112,
                "name": "episodes",
                "site": null,
                "link": null,
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": "Episode",
                "videoable_id": 169,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-08-29T18:58:22+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            },
            {
                "id": 113,
                "name": "episodes",
                "site": null,
                "link": null,
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": "Episode",
                "videoable_id": 169,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-08-29T18:59:52+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            },
            {
                "id": 114,
                "name": "episodes",
                "site": null,
                "link": null,
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": "Episode",
                "videoable_id": 169,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-08-29T19:01:01+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            },
            {
                "id": 115,
                "name": "episodes",
                "site": null,
                "link": null,
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": "Episode",
                "videoable_id": 169,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-08-29T19:01:24+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            },
            {
                "id": 116,
                "name": "episodes",
                "site": null,
                "link": null,
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": "Episode",
                "videoable_id": 169,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-08-29T19:02:21+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            },
            {
                "id": 117,
                "name": "ep 1",
                "site": null,
                "link": "sacsacs",
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": null,
                "videoable_id": 169,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-08-29T19:02:21+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            },
            {
                "id": 118,
                "name": "ep2",
                "site": null,
                "link": "casvsavsav",
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": null,
                "videoable_id": 169,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-08-29T19:02:21+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            },
            {
                "id": 119,
                "name": "episodes",
                "site": null,
                "link": null,
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": "Episode",
                "videoable_id": 169,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-08-29T19:02:54+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            },
            {
                "id": 120,
                "name": "ep 1",
                "site": null,
                "link": "sacsacs",
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": null,
                "videoable_id": 169,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-08-29T19:02:54+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            },
            {
                "id": 121,
                "name": "ep2",
                "site": null,
                "link": "casvsavsav",
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": null,
                "videoable_id": 169,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-08-29T19:02:54+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            },
            {
                "id": 125,
                "name": "episode 2",
                "site": null,
                "link": null,
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": "Episode",
                "videoable_id": 169,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-09-01T15:08:39+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            },
            {
                "id": 126,
                "name": "part1",
                "site": null,
                "link": "google.com",
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": null,
                "videoable_id": 169,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-09-01T15:08:39+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            },
            {
                "id": 127,
                "name": "part2",
                "site": null,
                "link": "google.com",
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": null,
                "videoable_id": 169,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-09-01T15:08:40+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            },
            {
                "id": 128,
                "name": "part3",
                "site": null,
                "link": "google.com",
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": null,
                "videoable_id": 169,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-09-01T15:08:40+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            }
        ],
        "seasons": []
    },
    {
        "name": "Gotham",
        "id": 269,
        "videos": [
            {
                "id": 167,
                "name": "Extended Trailer",
                "site": "YouTube",
                "link": "youtube.com/watch?v=0d1zpt6k5OI",
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": "Trailer",
                "videoable_id": 269,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-10-02T14:30:32+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            },
            {
                "id": 168,
                "name": "Gotham Villains",
                "site": "YouTube",
                "link": "youtube.com/watch?v=islRZ_ygKk8",
                "quality": null,
                "video_type": "Teaser",
                "videoable_id": 269,
                "videoable_type": "Tv",
                "created_at": "2014-10-02T14:30:32+05:00",
                "video_source": null,
                "video_source_cd": null
            }
        ],
        "seasons": []
    }
]
```